# Character Format in SQL

Tags: sql, format

I am new to SQL code writing. How do I format EmployeeID as character(9)? It is currently shown as an int. I need it as character(9) since I will be joining that field up to a different table.

SELECT  ,UserID
    ,EmployeeID

from    DASH.tblUserHierarchy

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserID,
       CAST(EmployeeID AS VARCHAR(9)) EmployeeID 
FROM DASH.tblUserHierarchy
```

This should work